# PHP mail function doesn't work with jQuery validation plugin

Tags: php, email, jquery-plugins, validation

I have a contact form that works fine.  However I'm trying to use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to check that there are no empty fields left before submitting, but when I add the plugin I no longer receive any emails.

The code is as follows:

Inside contact.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("Thank you for submitting your information.");
        },
    });
});
<form class="cmxform" id="myform" method="post" action="contact.php">
    <fieldset>
        <p><label for="cname">Name:</label> <input type="text" id="cname" name="name" maxlength="255" class="required" /></p>
        <p><label for="cemail">Email:</label> <input type="text" id="cemail" name="email" maxlength="255" class="required email" /></p>
        <p><label for="tel">Tel:</label> <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" maxlength="15" class="required" /></p>
        <p><label for="service">Service:</label>
            <select name="service">
                <option value="option1">Option1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option3</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p><label for="comments">Comments:</label><textarea class="textarea" id="comments" name="comments" rows="7" cols="1"></textarea></p>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And inside contact.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$header='From: '.$email."\r\n";
$header.='Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';

$msg='Message from: '.$name."\r\n";
$msg.='Email: '.$email."\r\n";
$msg.='Tel: '.$tel."\r\n";
$msg.='Interested in: '.$service."\r\n";
$msg.='Message: '.$comments."\r\n";
$msg.='Sent '.date("d/m/Y",time());
$msg.=utf8_decode('');

$to = 'example@hotmail.com, example@gmail.com, example@company.com';
$subject = 'Contact from website';

mail($to,$subject,$msg,$header);
}

header("Location: contact.html");
?>
```

I don't know what changes are required for the plugin to work with PHP mail function. I'd appreciate if someone can take a look and help me figure this out.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing [something](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) in your `submitHandler()`?

Comment: Pretty good chance you got downvoted because jQuery and PHP are utterly unrelated. I would start by checking your console log to see if there's an error - which btw there will be in some way, even if it is not obvious... like human error (see jprofitt's comment). Aside that, I certainly hope you don't really have your document ready chunk outside a script tag on your actual site.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering about the downvote :)  I will look into both of your suggestions.  And yes, the js part is inside script tags on the head of the document, I was just typing really fast here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly PHP had nothing to do.  I was missing `form.submit();` on the submitHandler function.  Thanks to jprofitt and Kai Qing.